# How To See All Properties of a Cell/Range

Tags: excel, vba, properties

I am new to VBA, and am trying to understand all the *stuff* (objects?) that I'm working with. I could broaden my question to all things (worksheets, names, classes) but it's probably easier to just ask: **Is there a way to list out ALL properties of a cell?**

Example, if I set to variable `cell=A1` I would like to see:

with cell

- .Address = "A1"
- .Column = 1
- .Row = 1
- .Height, formulaR1C1,Value etc, etc,

I do know that the watch tool can offer some help (especially for simple variables like Long). However for something like a `Range`, navigating this seems like an endless maze of parents, children, and intimidating phrases (think family reunion in Minnesota...).

I've tried googling various wordings of this post but I have not seen something close to what I'm looking for.

In my head, it seemed like there might be something like the below invalid code
(anything with an `_?` is obviously not a real thing in VBA...)

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("a1")

Dim p As Any_property_?

For Each p In cell.allPossibleProperties_?
    Debug.Print cell.p
Next p
```

As I type this out, I suspect this may not be possible, since the property types could be boolean, integer, string, arrays... etc. Anyway, so maybe the answer is: not possible.

Sorry if this is dumb question. If anyone can, help I'll be sure to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The watch window and the online documentation are good places to start.  VBA doesn't really do reflection though, so there's no way to loop over an objects properties/methods (though the Watch window already does that pretty well I think)

Comment: ...for properties that is, not methods.

Comment: Okay thanks. Yeah I meant the Watch Window when talking about the maze of options. Sounds like the answer is *NOT POSSIBLE*. If someone posts this, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody posted an answer (after more than 3 weeks), I guess I will just post the answer provided in comments:

**NO.** there is not a way to do this. Best solution is to use the p[roperties and watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/forms/add-a-watch-expression) tools.